# Is there a way to limit the number of microsoft hosted agents per project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a devops organization with lots of projects and ~30 microsoft hosted agents. Most of the projects are rather small and require only a few pipeline runs, one project is rather big and has lots of long running pipeline runs.

No matter how many ms-hosted agents we buy, we regularly run into the situation that the big greedy project saturates the pool and the smaller teams have to wait (sometimes hours) for their pipeline runs.

Is there any way to limit the agents on a project basis - or is the only workaround to move the big greedy project into a dedicated organization?

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature that can make certain number of Microsoft-hosted agents in the pool `Azure Pipelines` only work for a selection of projects. Currently, the permission for the pipelines in a project to use an agent is not managed on individual agent level but on its pool level.

For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

As of now, I am afraid the only workaround is to isolate the big greedy project in one organization separated from other projects. If possible, you may consider setting up and maintaining your own [self-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser)/[VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops) agent pool.